# VB6 data structure to perform two-criteria searches

Tags: data-structures, vb6

I'd like to use a VB6 in-memory data structure (Array? Collection? Whatelse?) that will enable searches with two criteria.

For example:

```
Fruit_structure
- key1 (non-unique)
- key2 (non-unique)
- data1
- data2
- data3
```

Pseudocode:

```
- Lookup [Fruit_structure] where key1 = "Lemon" and key2 = "Volkamer"
- if found a = data1, b = data2, c = data3
```

Wonderful if you could post a sample to load and retrieve data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Private Type dataHolder
    Key1 As String
    Key2 As String
    Data1 As String
End Type

Dim myDict(1 To 10) As dataHolder

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    myDict(1).Key1 = "aaa"
    myDict(1).Key2 = "bbb"
    myDict(1).Data1 = "entry 1"
    myDict(2).Key1 = "xxx"
    myDict(2).Key2 = "zzz"
    myDict(2).Data1 = "entry 2"
    myDict(3).Key1 = "kkk"
    myDict(3).Key2 = "qqq"
    myDict(3).Data1 = "entry 3"
    myDict(4).Key1 = "eee"
    myDict(4).Key2 = "rrr"
    myDict(4).Data1 = "entry 4"


    Dim result As dataHolder
    result = GetValue("kkk", "qqq")

    MsgBox result.Data1
End Sub

Private Function GetValue(Key1 As String, Key2 As String) As dataHolder
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(myDict) To UBound(myDict)
        If myDict(i).Key1 = Key1 And myDict(i).Key2 = Key2 Then
            GetValue = myDict(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: What if you have 4 data fields? Ie data1,data2,data3,data4...result will hold a comma separated value?

Comment: Ahhhhh ok, i didn't see the function. Now I've got it. I just need to modify Getvalue and the data structure. It won't be lightning fast, however it should work. Thanks!